# Possible to target specific TestNG.xml files via Maven POM File?

Tags: java, xml, maven, testing, selenium-webdriver

Possible to target only one of the two TestNG xml files listed within my Maven POM File?

My Maven POM file points to two xml files: uat.xml and preprod.xml, how do i target only one of the xml files using maven commands such as mvn clean compile test?

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <!--<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe</executable> -->
                    <executable>${env.JAVA_HOME}\bin\javac.exe</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>uat.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        <suiteXmlFile>preprod.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <testErrorIgnore>false</testErrorIgnore>
                    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See below. You will reference the file by name. So,

`mvn clean test -Dtestfile=uat.xml`

```
<configuration>
  <suiteXmlFiles>
    <suiteXmlFile>${testfile}</suiteXmlFile>
  </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```